# Is 'experience' countable or uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

"Seeing the Grand Canyon was certainly____(an /some) experience." 
Is experience countable or uncountable? Should I use some or an?

Comment: In fact, its countability or otherwise notwithstanding, we could still say ***an** experience.* Here the reference is to a slightly different concept.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary for **all** the meanings of 'experience?'

Comment: Ya I did.. 1- acquisition of skills and 2- have a first hand view or feeling of something

Comment: Please also visit our sister site [ell.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one meaning to the word 'experience,' the primary meaning being that of the mass noun. However, there is also the secondary meaning, which is **countable**:

ODO **[experience](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/experience)**

> **2** An event or occurrence which leaves an impression on someone:
>   *audition day is an enjoyable experience for any seven-year old*

Comment: So which experience should I consider countable and why?

Comment: See my comment at the question. It is the second meaning cited above that is used in the example sentence.

Comment: So the one which leaves impression is countable while the acquisition of skills one is uncountable..?

Comment: No, the one which is an individual event is countable, while the one that may be smeared over a long period is uncountable. (Yes, they are as you have said, but that does not seem to me to be a very useful way to distinguish them)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Yes**, *experience* can be countable or uncountable.

- Countable: She had several religious experiences in Lourdes.
- Uncountable: She has more experience with that than I do.